# Determine which variables in a given sas dataset are sort variables

Tags: sas

Ho can I determine which variables in a given SAS dataset are used in the sort of the dataset (if the dataset is sorted)?

I prefer to use one of the sashelp datasets, rather than proc contents.

Comment: So what did you try?

Comment: Sounds like OP tried `proc contents`, to me.  This is a reasonably good question.

Answer (score 2):

You can actually use the SASHELP views to find the answer.  If you run this step.

```
proc print data=sashelp.vcolumn;
 where libname='SASHELP'
   and memname like 'V%'
   and upcase(name) like '%SORT%'
 ;
run;
```

You will see that the variable SORTEDBY in the view SASHELP.VCOLUMN will have the indication of whether that variable is part of the sort key for a dataset. The value should show the order that the variables are to be used in the BY statement.